# Why no violation of Morgan's law happens in the following example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I got the following from the book `Discrete Mathematics with Applications 4th edition by Susanna Epp`.

> According to De Morgan’s laws, the negation of:
>
> `p: Jim is tall and Jim is thin` 
>  is `~p: Jim is not tall or Jim is not thin`
>
> Unfortunately, a potentially confusing aspect of the English language
>   can arise when you are taking negations of this kind. Note that
>   statement `p` can be written more compactly as
>
> `p´: Jim is tall and thin`
>
> When it is so written, another way to negate it is 
>   `~(p´): Jim is not tall and thin.` 
>   But in this form the negation looks like an *and*
>   statement.
>
> Doesn’t that violate De Morgan’s laws? Actually no violation
>   occurs. The reason is that in formal logic the words *and* and *or* are
>   allowed only between complete statements, not between sentence
>   fragments.

I have difficulty understanding the last paragraph. Why is it that in this example no violation of the Morgan's law happens?

Comment: Because it is  "Jim is not (tall and thin)."

Comment: In English it is sometimes unclear what is negated. "Jim is not tall and thin"  could mean Jim is thin and not tall, or it could mean Jim is neither tall nor thin, or it could mean that Jim is  either not tall or not thin or both. In everyday speech there is often a context of additional information that helps to indicate the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The *negation* ( properly speaking) of " Jim is tall and Jim is thin" is simply and purely :

> it is not the case that ( Jim is tall and Jim is thin).

And in general, the negaton of proposition P is simply

> ***NOT***-P .

- De Morgan's law tells you that the following sentence is ***equivalent*** to the negation of P, which is not exactly the same as being its negation  :

> it is not the case that Jim is tall OR it is not the case that Jim is
>   thin.

- The propositions not-(P&Q) and (not-P OR not-Q) are distinct syntactically, though they are equivalent semantically.
- Note that , in " John is not tall and thin" the "and" operator is within the scope of the negation operator. Since the main operator is " not" it is not an " and" statement.

In the same way the statement  : "not ( A Or B OR C OR D)" is not an OR statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the algebra of adjectives rather than of propositions, here "not tall and thin" is an abbreviation for "not (tall and thin)", and hence for "(not tall) or (not thin)". It would be clearer if we instead wrote "not *both* tall and thin".